# React application with independent component routing

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using react-router to manage the routing of the app.

My app is divided into two panels, and I would like to route them independently. Like a change of route would change only one panel or the other.

I tried something like this, but if I change route from `/conversations` to `/conversations/xxxxxx`, it reloads the side component.

```
export default (
  <div>
    <Route path="login" component={Login} />
    <Route path='/' component={requireAuthentication(Messenger)}>
      <Route path='/conversations' components={{side: ConversationContainer, main: DefaultPanel}} />
      <Route path='/conversations/:conversationId' components={{side: ConversationContainer, main: ActiveConversation}} />
      <Route path='/ended-conversations' components={{side: EndedConversationContainer, main: DefaultPanel}} />
      <Route path='/ended-conversations/:conversationId' components={{side: EndedConversationContainer, main: ActiveConversation}} />

      <Redirect from="/" to="/conversations" />
    </Route>
  </div>
);
```

EDIT: For example, let's say `/settings`, I would want to changes the left panel without changing whatever is on the right to display the new component in place of `ConversationContainer` by example.

I hope that is a bit clear. Is there a way to do this with the router ?
Otherwise I will need to use a state probably.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

React router helps you achieve this through nested routes. After configuring your routes, all that's needed is to access `{ this.props.children }` in the render method of any routes that have nested routes in them. Exactly which child components will be passed to the component is determined by your route configuration.

```
// router.js

<Route path="conversations/:conversationid component={Conversation}> // ".../conversations/1234"
  <Route path="began" component={BeginConversation} /> // ".../conversations/1234/began"
  <Route path="ended" component={EndConversation} /> // ".../conversations/1234/ended"
</Route>


// Conversation.js

render() { // In the render method of the component matching the container route

<div>
  <div className="left-panel">
    // Format left panel... this will not change on route began/ended route change
  </div>

   { this.props.children } // Tells react the render child components passed from your nested routes
</div>
```

Here are a couple useful resources!

- [React router docs & example on nested routes](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/Introduction.md)
- [A good thread on nested routes](http://react-router/RouteConfiguration.md%20at%20master%20%C2%B7%20reactjs/react-router)

Comment: Thank you for the response. If I want to add a route, let's say `/settings`, that changes the left panel without changing whatever is on the right.

It that possible ? I can't find any reference about something like this.

Comment: So it could be possible but your URLs might get a bit long. What is an example URL for this page? You could use parameters and then render the correct component based on that. For example: "http://.../conversation/leftpanel/settings/rightpanel/began". But that wouldn't be the independence you're looking for I don't think.

Comment: Yes that wouldn't be ideal.

Comment: Actually, I would like something like `/conversations` load the side panel, `/conversations/xxxxx` loads the conversation details on the right, `/conversations-ended` loads a different left-panel. And maybe `/settings` would also load a different left panel. And this, without changing the right content. This might not be possible, I understand that, but I wonder !

Comment: Ahh yes, you would need to use params for that is my understanding (if sticking with using routing instead of state).

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help ! I will try to use a state instead !